# Override numpy.matmul function

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, overriding, linear-algebra

I want to override **numpy.matmul()** function, such that instead of dot product of two matrix vectors, calculate how many elements are element-wise equal between those two vectors.

Example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: m1 = np.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

In [3]: m2 = np.matrix([[1, 3], [2, 4]])

In [4]: np.matmul(m1, m2)
Out[4]: 
matrix([[ 5, 11],
        [11, 25]])
```

Instead of the result above, I want to have following:

```
In [4]: myfunction(m1, m2)
Out[4]: 
matrix([[2, 0],
        [0, 2]])
```

**[1, 2] and [1, 2] dot product** is **5**, but I want **np.sum([1,2] == [1,2])**, which is **2**.
My question is how can I change in **np.matmul()** function **np.dot()** product of two **v1** and **v2** vectors with **np.sum(v1 == v2)**

Comment: I would say that redefining a built-in method is not a good practice... Why don't you just define your own and use numba for performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [93]: m1,m2=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]),np.array([[1,3],[2,4]])
In [94]: np.matmul(m1,m2)
Out[94]: 
array([[ 5, 11],
       [11, 25]])
```

The dot product can be calculated with:

```
In [95]: (m1[:,:,None]*m2[None,:,:]).sum(axis=1)
Out[95]: 
array([[ 5, 11],
       [11, 25]])
```

This doesn't have the speed of `matmul` because it doesn't pass anything to BLAS-like functions, but it is still reasonably fast, making full use of `numpy` array operations.

I think your desired version would be:

```
In [96]: (m1[:,:,None]==m2[None,:,:]).sum(axis=1)
Out[96]: 
array([[2, 0],
       [0, 2]])
```

Comment: I wouldn't give better  answer